# Difference between ArcSDE and ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

What is the difference between ArcSDE and ArcGIS Server?

Answer (score 6):

ArcSDE is a component of ArcGIS for Server.  However, it is a distinct server technology for providing geodata services from relational database management systems that pre-dates ArcGIS for Server.  For more details see [What is ArcSDE?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000500000001000000)

ArcGIS for Server provides a range of web services beyond simple geodata services: Feature, Map, Geocoding, Geoprocessing, Image, Globe, Web Editing, KML, OGC, etc.  For more details see [What is ArcGIS Server?](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000500000001000000)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a clear explanation of what the differences were and I came across a page for ArcGIS 10.3 that described ArcSDE and how it is included in desktop and it's limitations.

Scroll down to the section called.

[How is ArcSDE technology included in ArcGIS?](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/types-of-geodatabases.htm)

It looks like one can install the SQL server express edition (with all it's limitation) but you can only do stuff with it if you have at least the *Standard* license level.