# ArcGIS Terminology and Data Types

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, icon

What is the difference between a "Feature Class" and an "SDE Feature Class"?
Or a "Table" and an "SDE Table"?
When browsing data in ArcCatalog, hosted on the same enterprise gdb, I see these data types listed and am not sure what the difference(s) between them are.

Also, in the attached ArcCatalog screenshot below are two line feature classes.  Their icons are different.  Why are different icons signifying?[image]

Comment: One is a connection through SDE (spatial database engine) and the other is not. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65454/what-is-the-difference-between-arcsde-and-arcgis-server

Comment: How deep do you want to go? On the surface there's no difference to the end user except SDE *can* support multiple editors and the location isn't a file that you can find with explorer... but that's mostly important only for backup purposes. At the ArcObjects level SDE feature classes are opened by IRemoteDatabaseWorkspaceFactory using a property set where feature classes in geodatabases (and shapefiles) are opened using IWorkspaceFactory using open.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  Oscar, my question relates to files all the features I mentioned residing in the same enterprise gdb.  I know the differences between file and enterprise gdbs.  Chris, so within the same enterprise gdb connection in ArcCatalog, It is connection in two ways, via SDE and Direct Connect? I didn't think that was possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a link you can look regarding your first question:
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/45017

Comment: This could be considered a link only answer, which is generally discouraged. You should at least summarize the information within your answer, as links can go dead in the future rendering the answer useless.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, in the attached ArcCatalog screenshot below are two line feature classes. Their icons are different. Why are different icons signifying?

In answer to your second question. The first icon represents a regular SDE feature class. The second icon represents a feature class that hasn't been registered with the geodatabase.